# How do I model different informations into an object?

Tags: oop

I want to let a user choose different Payment Methods. So I have a class that describes a payment method.

```
public class PaymentMethod {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    //Constructors, Accessors...
}
```

Now I have a bean holding the choice of the user

```
public class OrderBean {
    private List<PaymentMethod> availablePayments;
    private PaymentMethod selectedPayment;
    private PaymentInformation paymentInfo;
}
```

My question is how to best model the `PaymentInformation` class. The problem I'm facing is, that depending on the selected PaymentMethod the information to hold in that object can be very different.

For example for the payment method "credit card", we need

- credit card number
- card security code
- owner
- expiration date

For paying by PayPal we need (I really don't know. Just to make my point.)

- Email Address

For paying with direct debit we need

- Owner
- account number
- credit institution

Here are a couple solutions I came up with so far:

Design three different classes. Let `OrderBean` have three different references and check that the right reference is filled according to the `selectedPayment`.

Let those three classes inherit from a common base class, or interface and check the actual type of the one reference that is in `OrderBean`.

Make one class for all payment information, together with a field of `PaymentMethod` and let the class check its members according to the `PaymentMethod`, itself.

And I'm sure there may be other ways, too.

So what is the best way to implement this?

Comment: I would appreciate it, if any body would come up with a better title, or more appropriate tags.

Comment: Is your payment method: CreditCard, paypall, ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PaymentInformation` and `PaymentMethod` are strongly related.
In my opinion `paymentInformation` should be a field of `PaymentMethod`. The `PaymentMethod` class should offer methods to fill its internal `paymentInformation`. The `PaymentInformation` class can be an inner class of PaymentMethod to express the correlation.

Can you think of a usecase of using `PaymentInformation` independently, e.g., storing it without the respective payment method? If yes you can create a shared `interface` for `PaymentInformation` but otherwise you do not need to do that.

--EDIT--

Regarding your repeated questions about where to check for the actual payment type in order to provide the payment-specific behavior:

Try to shift the reponsibility from your external code to the object, thus making the rest of your code payment-type agnostic. Instead of checking for `instanceOf` and then doing something, you should call a method of the paymentInformation (e.g. paymentInformation.createReport(), paymentInformation.issueBill()) etc. ) and let the actual payment method + information decide on their own how to behave. Because who else should know better than the actual object?

Comment: You should incorporate your comment to the other answer into this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would not create a class `PaymentMethod`, you could create an interface `PaymentInformation` with a method `getPaymentMethod` that each class, that implements this interface, needs to override.
Your `PaymentMethod` would be an enum (CREDIT_CARD, PAYPALL,...).

Each implementation now has the information you want.

In your `OrderBean` you can get the `PaymentMethod` by calling `paymnetInformation.getPaymentMethod()` where needed.

Comment: What about the `OrderBean`? Do I need to typecheck the reference of `PaymentInformation` then?

Comment: Whats the advantage of `PaymentInformation instanceOf CreditCardInfo` vs. `paymentInformation.getPaymentMethod().equals(CREDIT_CARD)`?

Comment: With my solution, you are using polymorphism. So you can use the PaymentInformation, without really caring if it's Paypall, CreditCard,... When using instanceOf, it's usually is a big if-statement and it indicates a poor design. There are a lot of better explenations from a lot smarter people then me to be found on the internet.

Comment: You have to shift the reponsibility from your external code to the object. Instead of checking for `instanceOf`and then doing something, you should call a method of the `paymentInformation` (e.g. `paymentInformation.createReport()`, `paymentInformation.issueBill()`) etc. ) and let the actual payment method + information decide on their own how to behave. Because who else should know better than the actual object?